# What kind of structure would you recommend for querying Max/Min over range efficiently as shown?

Tags: mysql, performance

### FW: just a heads up that I may have combined mysql syntax and SQL syntax. I work with SQL at work (aka, right now) and then use mysql for side projects so I may not have used proper syntax on everything (query should be correct) so please bear with me lol

I have a database consisting of prices for various parts aggregated by day (PartPrices). I want to run a query to see which parts grew in price the most and which declined in price the most over a date range. This date range could be from a start date to now or a start date to any period in time.

The schema looks as follows:

```
PartID | DateTime (Time stamp from start of day) | Price
```

Essentially what I have is as follows:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIMEOFFSET
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIMEOFFSET

WITH LastPartPrices AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
      (SELECT
          PartID
          ,DateTime
          ,Price
       FROM PartPrices
       WHERE PartPrices.DateTime <= @EndDate
       GROUP BY `PartID`, DateTime DESC, Price) t
   GROUP BY `PartID`),
HighestPartPrices AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
      (SELECT
          PartID
          ,DateTime
          ,Price
       FROM PartPrices
       WHERE PartPrices.DateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
       GROUP BY `PartID`, Price DESC, DateTime) t
   GROUP BY `PartID`),
LowestPartPrices AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
      (SELECT
          PartID
          ,DateTime
          ,Price
       FROM PartPrices
       WHERE PartPrices.DateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
       GROUP BY `PartID`, Price ASC, DateTime) t
   GROUP BY `PartID`)

SELECT
   Parts.ID
   ,Parts.Name
   ,Parts.Description
   ,LastPartPrices.Price AS LastPrice
   ,( (LastPartPrices.Price - HighestPartPrices.Price) / HighestPartPrices.Price ) AS HighCurrentDifference
   ,( (LastPartPrices.Price - LowestPartPrices.Price) / LowestPartPrices.Price ) AS LowCurrentDifference
FROM Parts
INNER JOIN LastPartPrices ON Parts.ID = LastPartPrices.PartID
INNER JOIN HighestPartPrices ON Parts.ID = HighestPartPrices.PartID
INNER JOIN LowestPartPrices ON Parts.ID = LowestPartPrices.PartID
```

I don't feel this query is optimized which is why I'm reaching out to the SO community for input. If you think I should handle this data differently, I'm open to suggestions as well. Thanks in advance. Here is some raw sample data from PartPrices (keep in mind, these are exaggerated to avoid having to add a ton of data):

```
{1, '2016-03-01T00:00:00+00:00', 150.40 },
{1, '2016-03-02T00:00:00+00:00', 170.50 },
{1, '2016-03-03T00:00:00+00:00', 160.00 },

{2, '2016-03-01T00:00:00+00:00', 80.30 },
{2, '2016-03-02T00:00:00+00:00', 100.00 },
{2, '2016-03-03T00:00:00+00:00', 120.00 },

{3, '2016-03-01T00:00:00+00:00', 10.50 },
{3, '2016-03-02T00:00:00+00:00', 20.10 },
{3, '2016-03-03T00:00:00+00:00', 30.00 }
```

What I would expect is to get the following:

```
{ 'ID', 'Name', 'Description', 'LastPrice', 'HighCurrentDifference', 'LowCurrentDifference' }
{ 1, 'Advil', 'Pain Killer', 160.00, -0.06, 0.06 },
{ 2, 'Bud Light', 'Beer', 120.00, 0.2, 0.49 },
{ 3, 'XBox One', 'Game Console', 30.00, 0.49, 1.85 }
```

Comment: Why do you tag `sql-server`, but your syntax seems to be `mysql`? There's no `GROUP BY col DESC` syntax. And why don't you use `MIN`/`MAX`?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: My bad, wrong tag. I'll add some sample data right now as well

Comment: @GordonLinoff sample data added

Comment: *I may have combined mysql syntax and SQL syntax*. No,`SQL` is a generic language, not a specific product like `Microsoft SQL Server` or it's dialect `T-SQL`. Microsoft's brainwashing is actually working quite well :-(

Comment: @dnoeth Okay, your comment doesn't help answer the question though.

Comment: You tagged `mysql` and your Select includes `WITH`, so you run the beta of MySQL 8, which supports Windowed Aggregates like  `LAST_VALUE`? Is there always a row for the last date in that range?